# Send a form using jQuery and check if it was submitted

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have 2 forms on my page and 1 of them has 2 different ways to be submited, a submit button and a jQuery on click event, it looks something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#img_send_form').click(function() {
            $('#form2').submit();
        });
    });
</script>

<form name="form1" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="field1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="send1"/>
</form>
<form name="form2" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="field1"/>
    <input type="text" name="field2"/>
    <input type="text" name="field3"/>
    <input type="text" name="field4"/>
    <input type="text" name="field5"/>
    <input type="text" name="field6"/>
    <input type="text" name="field7"/>
    <input type="submit" name="send2"/>
</form>
<img src="xxx" id="img_send_form"/>
```

What is  the best way to check if form2 was submmitted on php? Do I need to use isset for every form field ?

```
if (isset($_POST['field1'])||isset($_POST['field2'])||isset($_POST['field3'])||isset($_POST['field4'])||isset($_POST['field5'])||isset($_POST['field6'])||isset($_POST['field7']))
```

or is there another "better" way to do it?

Comment: add hidden field in both form and check hidden field value on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a hidden field to the second form, and in PHP check if it's set, in this case was used the second form

Answer (score 2):

Take Hidden Field with Same Name in Both Forms (but differ Ids if you need)

Then you will only need to check the that hidden field

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary to take hidden fields,

PHP :

```
if(isset['send2'])) { echo "Form2 submitted !" ;?> }
```

Comment: it doesn't work to me when I send it using the image

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#img_send_form').click(function() {
            $('#form2').submit();
        });
    });
</script>

<form name="form1" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="field1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="send1"/>
</form>
<form name="form2" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form2_send"/>
    <input type="text" name="field1"/>
    <input type="text" name="field2"/>
    <input type="text" name="field3"/>
    <input type="text" name="field4"/>
    <input type="text" name="field5"/>
    <input type="text" name="field6"/>
    <input type="text" name="field7"/>
    <input type="submit" name="send2"/>
</form>
<img src="xxx" id="img_send_form"/>
```

And php :

```
if(isset['form2_send'])) { echo "Form2 submitted !" ;?> }
```